# The effect of test set size on the performance of linear regression model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear

I have implemented a linear regression model and tried that on a dataset. The input has 8 features, and the output has 2. I split the train/test set as 80%/20%, 70%/30%, 60%/40%,...,20%/80%. I observed that the MSE of training set increased as the training set size increased, and the MSE of test set decreased as the training set increased. I know that more training data will make the model more accurate and thus decrease MSE in test set. But I'm not sure why the MSE of training set increased. Also, when I plot the MSE as a function of training set size, the MSE of training and test sets appear to be out of phase, is that normal?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I have questions!  Could you please explain "The input has 8 features, and the output has 2."  Also, what is your overall sample size?  And, when you say "the MSE of training set increased as the training set size increased," could you supply the sequence of MSE numbers, or display a graph of them by training-set sample size?  All of this will I think better enable someone here to give you an informed, helpful answer.